# Spring Boot - determining a sub-domain (with wildcard)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

New to Spring Boot here. Spring MVC provides the @SubdomainMapping annotation, which does not seem to be available from what I can see in Spring Boot. I've seen a few people discuss using a **filter** to handle this. Or other approaches that seem overly convoluted.

Would there not be a (simple/cleaner) way to handle all sub-domains within a standard controller such as:

```
@SubdomainMapping(value = {"**"}
public String data(ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request) {

//Code to handles subdomain logic here ....

}
```

This would be a simple approach where all values are treated equally with minor differences.

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I have worked on this myself and I have an answer that isn't as simple as you wanted, but I don't think there is one that simple.

So, you can create a handler interceptor adapter that will grab every request before it gets to your controller and grabs and processes the subdomain. This would require something like this:

```
@Component
public class SubDomainInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {


    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object, Exception arg3)
            throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object, ModelAndView model)
            throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object) throws Exception {
        String mysub = request.getRequestURL().toString();
        //...
        // Do whatever you need to do with the subdomain
        //
        if (isGoodSubdomain){
             session.sendAttribute("subdomain", mysub);
        } else {
             response.sendRedirect("http://www.basesite.com"):
        }
        return true;
    }
```

You then use that session variable in your controllers to filter values or whatever you need to use them for. I know this isn't the simple answer you wanted, but it was the best one that I have found so far.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I've come up with a solution using a customized interceptor that specifically handles the sub-domain issue. While handling this in a controller does work, I wanted to remove it further and push it to the interceptor level.

Comment: Could you post the solution that you did use, in case this is of interest to anyone but the two of us?